# How do cloud services 'link' together servers?

Tags: cloud

I really don't know how it works but I know cloud services aren't being hosted on a single machine so my question is what is happening to make this happen, what do I need to do the same with two servers and if it's really complicated is there somewhere I can learn about it or a specific keyword I can Google?

Comment: The most simple way to understand it is more then 1 everything, Multiple compute servers (doing the actual work for the customer), multiple storage nodes (data being on all of these nodes so if one fails it is no big deal), multiple network switches, multiple etc and then some various pieces of software technology's and if a server fails someone (or automatically) the customers stuff is moved to another node or if a customer requests more power they can increase it. It can be various softare, hardare etc technology's from various companies.

Answer (score 3):

"Cloud" is marketing double-speak for a wide variety of technologies. It is not some specific piece of technology, nor are the underlying technologies new to the industry.

Without asking a very specific question, there's no way we could possibly answer how one service is "linked" to another.

Answer (score 1):

```
client -->| load_balancer ___> server1 \
          |               \              == storage
          |                \_> server2 /
          |
          |__ this is the cloud ______________________
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time there will be racks of server linked together much like in a hadoop cluster.  However, each company is different on how they manage and cluster their servers.